# Implicit Declaration of Function sbrk( )

Tags: c

I am trying to create my own malloc function, and I did not finished yet. Here is related part of my code:

`mymalloc.h` :

```
#pragma once

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct METADATA{
    struct METADATA *next;
    struct METADATA *prev;
    int free;
    size_t size;
}METADATA;

METADATA *metadata;

void *mm_malloc(size_t size);
```

`mymalloc.c`

```
#include "mm_alloc.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

void *mm_malloc(size_t size) {
    if(size == 0)
        return NULL;

    METADATA *tmp;
    long address;

    if(metadata == NULL){
        sbrk(sizeof(tmp));
        sbrk(size);
        address = sbrk(0);

        return (void *)address;
    }
}
```

In the `sbrk(sizeof(tmp));` part of `mymalloc.c`, I got `"Implicit declaration of function sbrk()"`. What I wanted to do ise creating a place for `metadata` of new block and also a place for the required size. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to `man sbrk`, its declaration is located in unistd.h.

Comment: `sbrk` is obsolete today. Use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and study the implementation of *existing* `malloc`s in some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) C standard library (such as [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) or [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)....)

Comment: I missed that part, sorry for the stupid question. Thanks,

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Actually it is my homework, so I need to do with sbrk( ). But thanks anyway, I will look at that as well.

Comment: Depending on your environment/version/..., you may also need to define a feature test macro to remove the `sbrk` warning. Adding `#define _GNU_SOURCE` to the top of your file will remove the warning. This includes much more than you really need for sbrk, so check out the unistd.h to see the specific settings that are required for `sbrk`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the line

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

At the top of the file 'mymalloc.c' so that the function is declared